# Is there a facebook sharing link for only text status?

Tags: facebook, api, button

Is there any sharing link for facebook that only requires a textual status, not like the sharer which needs a url.

What i want is like the `twitter.com/?status=___` but for facebook.

The reason is that when i even put a url in the sharer, the title is overwritten with the real page url which is not good for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add metadata to your live page in order to specify a title, description and image. Facebook scans for appropriate content on the shared URL, but it takes time to update on the server -- so make sure you've got the content right the first time!

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

Scroll down to "Sharing Rich Media":
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share

Comment: Marcy thanks for your answer, but i already know that, what i want is to specify dynamically the title in the sharing link.

Comment: Ahh... sorry for the not so helpful answer. Here is a method one of my colleagues has been using, it should get you part of the way there: http://www.addthiscdn.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29539